# Spring boot create a topic and publish so APPS can receive it

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, mqtt

I'm creating an app that there's a button that says "Join the room" and when you click on it you join an imaginary room where you can see more users entering.
My idea is to create a topic for instance nameRoom and every time a user joins the room it automatically subscribe to them, so if there's another update he/she'll receive the update for instance one joined or one left.
The thing where I'm stuck is: 
The "Administrator" can create a "Room" so every time the Administrator creates a Room should it be a new topic, right? So, my question is once I'm inside a room, I'd like to create like a countdown let's say 30 seconds, and when those 30 seconds are done, it starts to ask me questions and everyone can answer the question and I need to see how many users have answered and how many does not, this is another topic?

The flow is :

1. Administrator creates a room --> Room1
2. User1 joins the Room1 and sees only you are in this room
3. User2 joins the Room and sees there are 2 guys in this room (And so on until user 5)
4. Then the timer goes down 30 to 0
5. Then as a User1 I see "How old is Michael Jordan" and 4 checkbox and everyone can answer
6. Also there's a field saying how many answers already have been posted so if the time of the question is 30 seconds and they are 5 users and they answer in less than 30 seconds the question has to be moved to the next screen that is
7. Top 3 who answered faster and score

To be clear :

I'd like to know how to create topic and then publish to them using Spring. For example to create the room is not necessary MQTT but to check who joins and this stuff it is, so I'm asking this, how could I create this with MQTT?

Also, MQTT would be responsible to say all of the info? I mean every room has some questions so it's necessary to via MQTT know the ranking etc?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I'm trying to understand how can I do it from the server/DB side with the MQTT stuff

Comment: Not sure if it helps but you can check the following repo: https://github.com/ddycai/spring-boot-chatrooms

Comment: @ArthurGurov would be good if there's an example that I can use something to interact with my apps too

Comment: Well APP notifications are not a simple thing. You should use Apple and Google mechanisms; for Apple you should use APN (Apple Push Notification service) while for Android you should use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)

Comment: @AngeloImmediata It's only for Android, I'm thinking to use MQTT to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my old project I created something similar to what you need.
I'm still sure Google (and Apple) notification systems are better. In any case here what you need.

You can use [Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/) in order to produce and consume MQTT messages.
In my android app build.gradle file I added:

```
 compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
```

Now there is a newer version of the library

This library offers to you all the needed API in order to consume and produce MQTT messages in and from an Android device.

In the documentation section you can find a sample application. You can start from there

On server side I used [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) as broker. It offers an embedded implementation of MQTT handler and you can create topics and queues in order to handle MQTT messages.

I hope it's useful

Angelo

**EDIT SECTION**

Let's suppose you want to use ActiveMQ on server side.

You must download and install activemq. In the activemq.xml file inside the directory `${activemq_home}/conf` you'll find the mqtt configuration. It's this line:

```
<transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

This means that activemq handles mqtt protocol messages on port 1883 (the mqtt default TCP/IP port).

On the admin console of activemq you can create topic or queue you want to use for your messages. In the app you must connect the paho service to the created topic or queue.

Please note that by default activemq uses in memory DB. I suggest to yuo to configure it in order to use normal RDBMS or even NoSQL DB. The most important thing is that you configure it in order to store all messages not in memory otherwise you can risk messages will be lost.

Moreover if you expose on internet activemq I strongly suggest to you to protect it by secure credentials or by using SSL certificates.

Comment: Could you explain me a little bit how should I create the broker and more or less the steps I have to do in  server side?

Comment: see my update section. Tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: That's cool, it's interesting I need to investigate more about ActiveMQ, but I'm wondering if for something small that I want, just create like a room that should be a topic or queue and then when the app joins the room it publishes and see the status whenever more are joining, and then from server side send to everyone subscribed a message and display it from the app, you got me?

Comment: Well what I’d do is the following: on server side (e.g. a web app) somebody (maybe administrator?) creates a room. This means to create also a topic or queue on activemq. At this point the app can show the active rooms and user can choose the room he/she wants to join. Here it’s all MQTT protocol. Once connected to the room the app will be connected to the room topic or queue and from server side we can publish MQTT messages. This messages can be consumed by all the listeners (apps and other clients). This is true also from the app to the server. Also on server you musthave a MQTT listener

Comment: Thanks, do you think that's a non complicated implementation?

Comment: Well I can talk by myself... I implemented it (well not a chatroom service but something else). The biggest issue I had was the notification management both in Android and iOS (I used to write native app); all the other stuffs implementations were pretty "simple" but it always depends on the subject who will do the work :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187652/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-angelo-immediata).

Comment: I'll try for sure

Comment: did you have time to take a look?

Comment: I answered on chat

Comment: Same, take a look please :P

Comment: Answered in chat

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to create database that suits your application needs

Database name : ChatRoom

Tables:

- Topics(To store all mqtt room topic names)
- Room (Each room is associated with a topic)
- User (Each user is associated with a room)

2) Setup an mqtt server which allows connection both on mqtt and websockets (To support javascript application)

3) Now create a spring boot application with following api and web pages

Web pages:

- chatroom.html
- chatroom.js

Api:

- create chatroom (for admin)
- list chatroom
- join chatroom (for new users)

Steps:

- The admin uses the chatroom.html web page to create new   chatroom.On creation it calls create chatroom api to create new chatroom. In the api it will subscribe to a new topic for new chatroom.
- When normal users visit chatroom.html it will list available chatrooms (use list chatroom api). Once you click on chatroom it will call join chatroom api to update the details in database. The javascript from browser can connect to mqtt topic for the specific chatroom.
- For managing questions you need to have your own logic in backend as well as frontend side. You can use Mqtt topic for transferring messages

Refer the following links

For javascript
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/using-javascript-mqtt-client-websockets/

For java 
https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/

```
public final class MessageQueueClient implements MqttCallback
{
    private MqttClient mqttClient;

    private MessageQueueClient() 
    {
    }

    public static MessageQueueClient getInstance() 
    {
        return messageQueueClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) 
    {
    }

    //Call this method on server startup to connect to mqtt server(spring boot app start)
    public boolean connect(String hostname, String clientuniqueid) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (mqttCredentialsDTO != null) 
            {
                MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
                options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
                options.setCleanSession(true);
                mqttClient = new MqttClient(hostname, clientuniqueid);
                mqttClient.connect(options);
                return true;
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Call this method on server shutdown to disconnect from mqtt server
    public boolean disconnect() 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (mqttClient != null) 
            {
                mqttClient.disconnect();
                mqttClient.close();
                return true;
            }
        } 
        catch (MqttException e) 
        {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //call this method after mqtt connection established to subscribe to any topic
    public boolean subscribe(String topicName, int qos) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (topicName != null) 
            {
                mqttClient.subscribe(topicName, qos);
                return true;
            }
        } 
        catch (MqttException e) 
        {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return false;
    }


    //call this method after mqtt connection established to publish to any topic
    public boolean publish(String topicName, String message, int qos) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (topicName != null) 
            {
                MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage();
                mqttMessage.setPayload(message.getBytes());
                mqttMessage.setQos(qos);
                mqttClient.publish(topicName, mqttMessage);
                return true;
            }
        } 
        catch (MqttException e) 
        {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Santosh, would be a possibility to explain me how from server side I create all of this broker and stuff? I'm unsing Spring boot, but I don't know if the page will be on the same project or a different one, I mean Server Spring in one project Angular (frontend) in other project and Android in other project

Comment: Hi @StuartDTO i have modified the answer with code that shows how to connect to mqtt server, disconnect, subscribe and publish to mqtt. Connect and disconnect methods has to be called on start and stop of your application respectively

Comment: But, about spring boot? I need to create a topic, to send it to the app, so they can subscribe to it, right? I need to know how to create the backend stuff first. then I can create the frontend and app side, but first I should create something about the answer of @Angelo, right?

Comment: The code i have shared is a mqtt client to be used in your spring boot app. For the topic you can do in two ways. Use one topic for all chat rooms or dynamically create topic based on rooms created. There are many ways in which you can achieve your goal. I have suggested you one of the way. First try to create a prototype and then try to perfect your design. You will learn more only during development phase.

Comment: Have you worked with this or created something similar? You look like you have used it before, and maybe you can help me out if I have some doubts...

Comment: Hi, can I send to you an email or something to ask you a question please?